# Test Firebase cloud function accessing outbound networks (Expo server sdk)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, expo

I need to automate push notifications to my Expo app through Firebase cloud functions. the free plan doesn't allow sending requests to outbound networks such in my case (Expo server) so I have to upgrade to a paid plan.
So before I upgrade, can I test it locally or something ?

Comment: If you are just going to test some Cloud Functions it shall not cost anything. In other words, you have to give your credit card details but nothing is going to be charged. As said in the Pricing doc "On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier. The first 2,000,000 invocations, 400,000 GB-sec, 200,000 CPU-sec, and 5 GB of Internet egress traffic is provided for free each month. You are only charged on usage past this free allotment."

Comment: See [run functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) in the Firebase documentation.